# How would I use a serial EEPROM as a parallel EEPROM in a breadboard computer build?

Tags: i2c, eeprom

I have been thinking of building Ben Eater's 8 bit computer (on a budget) for some time now but the only EEPROMs I can find are serial EEPROMs with I2C interface. I am wondering if I can use a serial EEPROM as a parallel EEPROM. If so, **How can I?**

Comment: Write code to do it. Read and write from the I2C interface instead of a direct memory access. It will be very slow.

Comment: Welcome.  Do you mean the 2816 that's part of the [output register](https://eater.net/8bit/schematics)?  And the pair in the control logic?

Comment: Yes you can but it is so complex and slow that it is not feasible and you really don't want to do it. Don't use parallel EEPROMs then, use more modern chips like Flash.

Comment: Why can't you use parallel _flash_ (emulated eeprom)? Took me around 5 seconds to find a ton of such ICs.

Comment: @LiorBilia I think i will go with your approach for the control word, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two U47 and U52 are organised as a 1k x 16 bit ROM (A10 tied low).  You might consider it cheating, but it's perfectly possible to program an ATmega328 as a 1k x 8 ROM.  It sits looking at its input (address) lines, puts an appropriate byte out of 8 outputs.  You see that chip enable and output enable both hard-wired active.

If you put it on a little circuit-board it would even be pin compatible!  You could consider using their TX/RX and having some kind of RAM-based Eater CPU microcode.

You'll have to check clock speeds.

[image]
From [Eater web site](https://eater.net/8bit/schematics)

In fact, if you look at the A7 address lines, they're tied high and low.  (Are the two ROMs programmed with the same content, half used for each?)

U45 appears to be a seven-segment decoder or similar.  Consider using a dedicated part for that if you don't want a third ATmega.

[image]
From [Eater web site](https://eater.net/8bit/schematics)